# Trouble with Java interfaces

Tags: java, interface, compiler-errors

I'm having trouble using an interface with another class.

I have an Animal class, a Pet class and a PetInterface class. The Pet class extends the Animal class and the PetInterface class extends JFrame.

My problem is that I need to use methods from the Pet class in the PetInterface class, for example:

```
JLabel happinessLabel = new JLabel(gethappiness());
```

I have no idea how to get this to work. whenever I use

```
public class Pet extends Animal implements PetInterface {
```

it tells me that "The type PetInterface cannot be a superinterface of Pet; a superinterface must be an interface".

Comment: `PetInterface` is clearly not an interface, it's a class.

Comment: *"My problem is that I need to use methods from the Pet class in the PetInterface class"*  That makes a total of 0 sense.

Comment: Specifically, an interface has no implementation, therefore cannot depend on methods from another class.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the potential design pitfalls here, it looks like you've declared PetInterface as a class instead of a public interface.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `extends` for an interface until and unless child is also an interface.

In the same way you can't use `implements` for a class.

```
class PetInterface extends JFrame{}
class Pet extends Animal implements PetInterface {} //PetInterface is not an interface
```

You have chosen a contradicting name for `PetInterface` whereas it's actually a `class`. Sometime it creates confusion.

---

**Points to remember:**

- An interface can extends multiple interfaces
- A class can implements multiple interfaces
- A class can extends single class

Some samples to make it clear.

```
interface InterfaceA{}
interface InterfaceB extends InterfaceA{} // valid 
// extends an interface where child is also an interface

class InterfaceA{}
class InterfaceB implements InterfaceA {} // invalid 
// implements a class

interface InterfaceA{}
class InterfaceB extends InterfaceA {} // invalid 
// extends an interface where child is a class

interface InterfaceA{}
interface InterfaceC{}
interface InterfaceB extends InterfaceA,InterfaceC{} // valid
// extends multiple interfaces
```

Answer (score 0):

PetInterface is class when you use 'implements' keyword with class. java throws such exception

Answer (score 0):

An interface in java doesn't mean it's a User Interface. Please review definition of what is an Interface here : [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_(Java)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_%28Java%29)